# What is the tick rate and the damage per tick of each circle?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

In PUBG, each circle deals damage in a constant tickrate. The damage dealt increases with each circle while the tickrate seems constant. At the time of writing this question, damage dealt is constant no matter the distance to the next circle, which was changed in a later update. Assuming the player is not boosted, how much damage in HP% does each circle deal per tick?

This information would be helpful to assess, at what HP% you would have to take meds (Med Kit, First Aid Kit, ...) to avoid dying to the zone.

Comment: From what I experienced, you can only outheal/run the first 2 blue circles, assuming you are on foot and didn't take healing buff before entering the blue circle. Third ticks in circles after that will kill you quicker than you can heal as it takes too long to apply a first aid/med kit at lower HP to make the heal worth it.

Comment: Note that an update today changed how this mechanic works - you now take more damage if you are farther from the safe zone (doesn't apply to first circle)

Comment: I edited the question to reflect that it is now outdated. I think that for the updated damage dealing a separate question might be necessary. But probably when things are settled

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [reddit analysis video](https://www.reddit.com/r/PUBATTLEGROUNDS/comments/6odhok/circle_breakdown_times_damage_travel_time_and_tips/) that goes more in depth. But he posted the stats below it as well:

> - Circle 1 Length - 4550m Damage - 0.4% Survive for - 4:10 Travel time - 5:00
> - Circle 2 Length - 2970m Damage - 0.6% Survive for - 2:46 Travel time - 2:20
> - Circle 3 Length - 1480m Damage - 0.8% Survive for - 2:05 Travel time - 1:30
> - Circle 4 Length - 740m Damage - 1% Survive for - 1:40 Travel time - 1:00
> - Circle 5 Length - 360m Damage - 3% Survive for - 0:34 Travel time - 0:40
> - Circle 6 Length - 175m Damage - 5% Survive for - 0:20 Travel time -
>     0:30
> - Circle 7 Length - 90m Damage - 7% Survive for - 0:15 Travel
>     time - 0:30
> - Circle 8 Length - 40m Damage - 11% Survive for - 0:10
>     Travel time - ~

As of 26-10-2017 there was an update changing the damage to be increased the further away one from the safe-zone circle is. Meaning this information is no longer correct.

Comment: There was a patch today that makes it so that the farther you are from the safe zone, the more damage (doesn't apply to the first circle however).  So unfortunately, this is now out of date.

Comment: Indeed, which is why I unset this as "accepted answer"

Comment: @ckuepker Being out of date doesn't mean the answer is suddenly invalid for when it was asked.

Comment: @KevinTheGreat You are right. I edited the question to reflect this and accepted this answer again.

Answer (score 5):

There is a Handy Chart that I found on Reddit that summarizes how much damage each circle does, as well as when you need to heal in order to survive. The amount of health in which you need to start Healing assumes you are using either a First-Aid kit or Medkit, boosts will make it easier to survive (as they will passively heal you while you are using the First-Aid or Medkit). Keep in mind that medkit's take 8 seconds to use whereas First-aid only takes 6 seconds, so it is safer to First-aid, then Medkit if you have the resources to spare.

**Circle Damage Summarized, and when you should Medkit/First Aid**
Circle 1: 0.50 dps       Heal before: 5%
Circle 2: 0.75 dps       Heal before: 8%
Circle 3: 1.00 dps       Heal before: 10%
Circle 4: 1.50 dps       Heal before: 15%
Circle 5: 3.00 dps       Heal before: 30%
Circle 6: 5.00 dps       Heal before: 50%
Circle 7: 7.50 dps       Heal before: 77%
Circle 8: 11.0 dps       Just Heal immediately
Circle 9: 11.0 dps       Just Heal immediately (you will probably die anyway)

[image: Blue Zone Chart]

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/PUBATTLEGROUNDS/comments/6fxbvl/blue_zone_marathon_guide/).